# The cursor broke in Visual Studio 2019 in a code editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When trying to move the cursor in code editor to the right / left / down / up using the arrows, the cursor does not move. Instead, Visual Studio switches from the code editor to changing the size of the text in the editor (click on the left arrow), changing the project (click on the up arrow), starting code cleanup (click on the down arrow), nothing happens when you click on the right arrow. In addition, all hotkeys don't work (F5, Ctrl+S, Ctrl+B, etc.) `Delete` and `Backspace` do not work too, but `Ctrl+Z` works.

All this applies only to Visual Studio 2019, everything works fine in other text editors

I didn't change any settings, everything worked fine yesterday. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

[Start cursor position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Yx8.jpg)

[What happens when I Click on the left arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZoKz.png)

[What happens when I Click on the up arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9pgz.png)

[What happens when I CLick on the down arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Xs6.png)

Comment: I wonder if one of your other modifier keys is stuck "logically or physically" - have you tried bashing every Ctrl/Alt/AltGr/Shift a few times on every keyboard connected to your computer? Have you tried resetting your key shortcuts using Tools->Options->Keyboard, choose (Default) and click Reset. If you open On Screen Keyboard are any keys lit up like they are being held down? If you unplug your keyboard(s) and use the on screen keyboard does it behave?

Comment: @CaiusJard, Reset key shortcuts helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your shortcuts with

Tools->Options->Keyboard, choose (Default) and click Reset